# Prove if $f$ and $g$ are simple functions then $fg$ is a simple function.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove if $f$ and $g$ are simple functions then $fg$  is a simple function.

**My attempt**
Let $(X,\mathbb{A})$ a measurable set, let $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ simple functions. in other words: $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{A_i}\space\space\space\text{with $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A_i\in\mathbb{A}$}$$

$$g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nb_i1_{B_j}\space\space\space\text{with $b_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B_j\in\mathbb{A}$}$$

Then,

$$f(x)g(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{A_i})(\sum_{j=1}^nb_i1_{B_j})=\sum_{i,j}^na_ib_j1_{A_i}1_{B_j}$$

Here i'm stuck

Comment: I'm not sure why or where you're stuck. What confuses you?

Comment: I need simplify $1_{A_i}1_{B_j}$

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_{A_i}\mathbf{1}_{B_j}=\mathbf{1}_{A_i\cap B_j}$

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: By "dot", as in, $f(x).g(x),$ do you mean ordinary multiplication? If so, the `\cdot` command in $\LaTeX$ is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write well. Just you have:
$$ 1_X \cdot 1_Y = 1_{X \cap Y}$$